# I want to display image using rest web services

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I need to display Image using rest web services I have around 100 images which are in web content-->images folder i want to display using URL

Comment: @GET
 @Path("/get")
 @Produces("image/png")
 public BufferedImage getFile() throws IOException {
  File file = new File("E:/KOTiCONS/Images/VADA.jpg");
  return ImageIO.read(file);
 } // here I am trying to read one image but If i am having 100 images and i need to keep in web content and i want to read from web content

Answer (score 0):

```
@GET
@Path("/get/{fileName}")
public BufferedImage getFile(@PathParam("fileName") String fileName) throws Exception {
    return ImageIO.read(new File("E:/KOTiCONS/Images/" + fileName));
}
```

Comment: It is giving java.io.IOException: The image-based media type image/webp is not supported for writing